# salt-master is not receiving scheduled job event fired on salt-minion

Tags: salt-stack, job-scheduling

I would to like to ask you for a help. I use saltstack as a job scheduler for slaves (minions) and I would like to be able to see on master job events fired on minion.

**My setup**

Job is scheduled on salt-master using a pillar for given minion. Pillar is:

```
schedule_returner: mongo
schedule:
  cmd:
    function: cmd.run
    args:
      - date +%s >> /tmp/job_runs
    minutes: 1
    maxrunning: 1
```

Scheduled job is executed without any problem on minion. I can see returned data in mongodb and a new timestamp in my dummy file `/tmp/job_runs`. The configuration file on minion `/etc/salt/minion.d/_schedule.conf` is:

```
schedule:
  __mine_interval: {enabled: true, function: mine.update, jid_include: true, maxrunning: 2, minutes: 60, return_job: false}
  cmd:
    args: [date +%s >> /tmp/job_runs]
    function: cmd.run
    maxrunning: 1
    minutes: 1
```

This file was generated and I didn't modify it.

In minion log I can see:

> [DEBUG   ] SaltEvent PUB socket URI:
>   /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_1fa42d8010_pub.ipc
>       [DEBUG   ] SaltEvent PULL socket URI: /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_1fa42d8010_pull.ipc
>       [DEBUG   ] Initializing new IPCClient for path: /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_1fa42d8010_pull.ipc
>       [DEBUG   ] Sending event: tag = __schedule_return; data = {'fun_args': ['date +%s >> /tmp/job_runs'], 'jid': 'req', 'return':
>   '', 'retcode': 0, 'success': True, 'schedule': 'cmd', 'cmd':
>   '_return', 'pid': 10264, '_stamp': '2017-02-22T10:03:05.750874',
>   'fun': 'cmd.run', 'id': 'vagrant.vm'}
>       [DEBUG   ] Minion of "salt" is handling event tag '__schedule_return'
>       [DEBUG   ] schedule.handle_func: Removing /var/cache/salt/minion/proc/20170222100305532940
>       [DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded mongo.returner

Now I'm interested in listening to those events with tag `__schedule_return`.
On minion, I can run the following commands:

```
wget https://raw.github.com/saltstack/salt/develop/tests/eventlisten.py
sudo python eventlisten.py -n minion
```

The output of `eventlisten.py` is correct and I can see this event.

**Now my question is:** Is there any way to listen to this events on salt-master?

When I run almost the same commands on master:

```
wget https://raw.github.com/saltstack/salt/develop/tests/eventlisten.py
sudo python eventlisten.py
```

I'm not able to see those events fired on minion by my scheduled job.
My motivation to do this is that I'm running saltpad on my master and I would like to see my scheduled jobs in the recent jobs (websockets...).

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

## Listening for Events

The quickest way to watch the event bus is by calling the `state.event runner` on you salt-master:

```
salt-run state.event pretty=True
```

## Firing Events

It's possible to fire an event to be sent up to the master from the minion using the `event.send` execution function:

```
salt-call event.send '__schedule_return' '{success: True, message: "It works!"}'
```

## Reactor System

Salt's Reactor System gives the ability to trigger actions in response to an event. Reactor SLS files and event tags are associated in the master config file (*by default `/etc/salt/master` or `/etc/salt/master.d/reactor.conf`*).

In the master config section 'reactor:' you can specify a list of event tags to be matched. Each event tag can have a list of reactor SLS files to be run.

```
# Master config section "reactor"
reactor:
  # Match tag "__schedule_return"
  - '__schedule_return':
    # Things to it matches the tag
    - /srv/reactor/do_stuff.sls
```

See the documentation about the [reactor system](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/reactor/index.html) for more information about salt's reactor system.